# ¿Cómo enviar más datos a una petición ajax?

Tags: php, ajax

En la página principal **index.php** tengo varia información obtenida por medio de sesiones, por ejemplo el `id` del usuario, entre otros datos.

Ahora tengo un formulario con un solo campo (`input`)

```
<form id="tck" method="POST" action="employee.php">
    <input type="text" name="ticket" maxlength="10">
    <button type="submit">ticket</button>
</form>
```

Cómo puedo enviar más datos a la petición `ajax` sin añadir más campos al formulario.

Necesito poder recibir de la petición `ajax` el `id` del usuario **(id_usuario)**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() { //document.ready es obsoleto desde jQuery 3

        $('.dismiss').click(function () {
            $('.response').fadeOut(500);
        });

        $('#tck').on('submit', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();     

            var data = $(this).serialize();

            var request = $.ajax({
                url: $(this).prop("action"),
                method: $(this).prop('method'),
                data: data,
                dataType: "html"
            });

            request.done(function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                    $('.response').html(response);
                    $(".response").fadeIn(200);
                    window.setTimeout(function () {
                        $('.response').fadeOut(500);
                    }, 6000);

            });

            request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
                alert('Hubo un error: ' + textStatus);
            });         

        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: lo que quiere es obtener varios datos con ese solo `input`, y todos enviarlos por la petición `AJAX`?

Comment: @Michael Realmente solo necesito enviar el `id` del usuario pero no tengo que añadir ningún campo al formulario, ni tampoco en modo oculto, en la página **index.php** es fácil imprimir el `id` del usuario, pero ese `id` necesito enviarlo por medio de `ajax` a la pagina **employee.php** que es donde se realiza la petición.

Comment: Tiene el `id_usuario` en `index.php` y necesita enviarlo en la misma petición `AJAX` de su ejemplo, a `employee.php`, si ? no me termina de quedar clara su pregunta.

Comment: @Michael Es exactamente lo que has dicho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para enviar más datos a través de `AJAX` puede usar el formato de datos `JSON` en ese caso lo que puede hacer es modificar la variable `data`:

```
var data = {
    serial : $(this).serialize(),
    idUsuario : Id_usuario //esta seria la variable en donde tiene este dato
}
```

y en `PHP` para recibir los datos lo hace así:

```
$serial = $_POST['serial'];
$idUsuario = $_POST['idUsuario'];
```

de esta forma puede agregar todos los datos que desee y obtenerlos uno a uno en `PHP`